Controlling an RF SP8T switch via a 15-pin D-sub using Python
In my application of interest, an RF SP8T switch is required to sequentially connect 8 receiver antennas to one network analyzer port, and I've found an affordable one on ebay,

Link to the Manufacturer's website
There is a D-sub connector at the back with 15 pins, 8 of which should correspond to the 8 states of the switch, one for ground, and one for the 12-volt supply (I don't know the purpose of the remaining 5 pins).

I'm thinking of a way to control the D-sub pin voltages with arduino, and probably there should be an intermediate circuitry to match the high-current demand (low impedance) to the low-current (high impedance) arduino pins.
What is the minimum set of hardware that I can use with python on Ubuntu to access all states of such a switch?

we don't do discussions here, I'm afraid – this is strictly a question & answer site. However, just ignoring your first sentence, this is very clearly a question – "what is the minimum  set of hardware …?" is an answerable question.

also, we need to know about the interfaces your Ubuntu machine has. And: why is this tagged [tag:arduino] and [tag:rs232]? neither appear in your question, and they seem neither conductive nor related to a solution.

Thanks for your feedback, Marcus. I will remove the first sentence then.

The ebay listing shows the part number as SP8T-0A-18A-TC002. However, the Link to the Manufacturer's website doesn't seem to define that specific part number. The Model Numbering System suggests the 'C' means Custom option. Therefore, without asking EPX MICROWAVE it might not be possible to determine the control mechanism to use. This is the issue with sourcing second hand components.

@MarcusMüller, Thanks again. I removed the "RS232" keyword. However, the "arduino" keyword is mentioned in the problem statement. Only COM and USB connectors are available on my Ubuntu machine.

From what's written, it appears that the pins of the connector are simply connections to what might be relays in the unit. So there is no RS-232, COM, or USB involved. You must get proper documentation from the supplier or else the part is unusable.

@ChesterGillon, thanks for going over the guide. I also went over the model numbering guide, and I could only follow the numbering up to 'SP8T-0A-18A'.

@Behnaam My reading of the model numbering guide is that the TC002 starts as the OPTIONS where 1) T means "Internal Terminations" 2) C means "Custom - - Customer specified requirements" 3) Don't what the 002 suffix means but might be customer specific.

@Chester, yes, that is also my understanding. Your exaplanation helps me to be more confident about my understanding of the guide :). I guess I wanted to read it conservatively.

You need to know the voltage and current requirements for the control signals. As far as i can tell you dont.
Depending on your frequency and power requirements there are other rf switches that can be driven directly from, say, a raspberry pi.

you could carefully test whether TTL levels suffice for switching, though. If that's not the case, try with 12 V (and a conservative current limit for the beginning). Whether that reverse engineering is good enough for OP's measurement purposes: who knows but OP?

@MarcusMüller, from the description in [link]{https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256805874758789.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2usa4itemAdapt#nav-specification}, it seems that if I connect pin j (j: 1, 2, ..., 8) to a 12-volt source with respect to pin 9, the RFC to RF_j path will be activated. I'm not sure what the current requirement is. For sure this switch is not solid-state and likly mechanical. So, activation of each pin requires 12 volt and a non-negligible amount of current (I'm guessing mA-level but higher than what a microcontroller can provide).

the manufacturer website explicitly lists TTL inputs for some models. the switch can be mechanical, but that doesn't mean the control voltage needs to directly drive the relay/coil.

@Marcus, yes, at the end some reverse engineering is needed to find the function of the pins. Stating the obvious, I probably need to find a cable with D-sub connector and stip off the cover to have easier access to the pins.
To summarize, I have 8 loads to bias with 12 volt, possibly with high current demand. I found the answer to this question helpful and relevant.

DA-15 connectors should be readily available - probably more available than a cable with connectors that you can chop up.

Yes, I found some inexpensive ones on Digikey. Thanks @PeterBennett!

The other 5 pins are there because plugs in this style come  with 9,15,25,or 37 pins, and 9 pins was too few.
It's also possible that the motor supply uses pins in parallel to increase the current carrying capacity, or has different pins for clockwise and anticlockwise... also probably the signal ground that is separate from the power ground.
It seems to have screws so you will be able to look inside and see how it's set up.
Minimum extra hardware, assuming the 8 outputs switch to a separate common that is not connected to the motor wires would be a low-side MOSFET to control the motor, a DA15 female plug, and wires.

From here, I understood why you mentioned "low-side". The instructions here are clear and simple to follow. So, I either need to build 8 MOSFET channels on a breadboard or buy an 8-channel MOSFET driver board. Suggestions are welcome if any one is aware of an 8-channel MOSFET board sold in the US.

After you buy it measure resistances between all pins and see what shows up.. that will give some clues as to what is inside it.  I think 1 MOSFET  output and 8 inputs but that's a guess.

Thanks @Jasen. If I understood correctly, you sepculate that there is already a driver board inside. Even with no MOSFET inside, I guess it's a good idea to measure the good old Thevenin resistance. I need that to choose the right MOSFET/BJT and resistors to make sure I will not overdrive each of the 8 loads under 12 V.
It's difficult to guess since none of the suppliers mentioned any thing about Imax.

I think there might be one load and 8 outputs inside
